# Xamarin.Android return live preview control back to camera after recording video

Tags: camera, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Froms (UWP, iOS, and Android) to render a Camera preview screen, where the user can take either a photo or a video.  The photo capture works perfectly (on all platforms).  I am having issues with the Android custom renderer and control.  The video capture works, but I cannot restore the live preview afterwards.  I either get Reconnect failure or startPreview failure exceptions.

Here is my custom renderer

```
public sealed class DroidCameraPreview : ViewGroup, ISurfaceHolderCallback
{
    public SurfaceView surfaceView;
    public ISurfaceHolder holder;
    Camera.Size previewSize;
    IList<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes;
    IWindowManager windowManager;

    public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

    Camera _camera;
    public Camera Preview
    {
        get { return _camera; }
        set
        {
            _camera = value;
            if (_camera != null)
            {
                supportedPreviewSizes = Preview.GetParameters().SupportedPreviewSizes;
                RequestLayout();
            }
        }
    }

    private MediaRecorder _mediaRecorder;

    public MediaRecorder Recorder
    {
        get { return _mediaRecorder; }
        set { _mediaRecorder = value; }
    }

    public DroidCameraPreview(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        AddView(surfaceView);
        windowManager = Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        IsPreviewing = false;
        holder = surfaceView.Holder;
        holder.AddCallback(this);
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        if (supportedPreviewSizes != null)
        {
            previewSize = GetOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        surfaceView.Measure(msw, msh);
        surfaceView.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Preview != null)
            {
                Preview.SetPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (Preview != null)
        {
            Preview.StopPreview();
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
    {
        var parameters = Preview.GetParameters();
        parameters.SetPreviewSize(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
        RequestLayout();
        switch (windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation)
        {
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                Preview.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                break;
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                Preview.SetDisplayOrientation(0);
                break;
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                Preview.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
                break;
        }
        Preview.SetParameters(parameters);
        Preview.StartPreview();
        IsPreviewing = true;
    }

    Camera.Size GetOptimalPreviewSize(IList<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h)
    {
        const double AspectTolerance = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double)w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = double.MaxValue;
        int targetHeight = h;
        foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
        {
            double ratio = (double)size.Width / size.Height;

            if (Math.Abs(ratio - targetRatio) > AspectTolerance)
                continue;
            if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
            {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
        if (optimalSize == null)
        {
            minDiff = double.MaxValue;
            foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }        
}
```

And here is my Android custom control.

```
public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyApp.CameraPreview, MyApp.Droid.DroidCameraPreview>
{
    DroidCameraPreview cameraPreview;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyApp.CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            cameraPreview = new DroidCameraPreview(Context);
            SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            e.OldElement.TakePictureChanged -= TakePicture;
            e.OldElement.StartVideoRecordChanged -= StartVideoRecord;
            e.OldElement.StopVideoRecordChanged -= StopVideoRecord;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.CameraOptions);
            Control.Recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            e.NewElement.TakePictureChanged += TakePicture;
            e.NewElement.StartVideoRecordChanged += StartVideoRecord;
            e.NewElement.StopVideoRecordChanged += StopVideoRecord;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Control.Preview.Release();
            Control.Recorder.Release();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private async void TakePicture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureCallback pc = new PictureCallback(cameraPreview.MediaFilename.FullName + "jpg");
        Control.Preview.TakePicture(pc, pc, pc);
        await pc.TCS.Task;
    }

    private class PictureCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Camera.IPictureCallback, Camera.IShutterCallback
    {
        private string FileName;
        public TaskCompletionSource<bool> TCS = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        public PictureCallback(string fileName)
        {
            FileName = fileName;
        }

        public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            File pictureFile = new File(FileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            if (data != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.Write(data);
                    fos.Flush();
                    TCS.SetResult(true);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    TCS.SetException(e);
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {
                    TCS.SetException(ie);
                }
                finally
                {
                    fos?.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        public void OnShutter() { }
    }

    private void StartVideoRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Control.Preview.StopPreview();
        Control.Preview.Unlock();
        Control.Recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
        Control.Recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        Control.Recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
        Control.Recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
        Control.Recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
        Control.Recorder.SetOutputFile(cameraPreview.MediaFilename.FullName + "mp4");
        Control.Recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(Control.holder.Surface);
        Control.Recorder.Prepare();
        Control.Recorder.Start();
    }

    private void StopVideoRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control.Recorder.Stop();
        Control.Recorder.Reset();
        //Control.Recorder.Release();
        Control.Preview.Lock();
        //Control.Preview.Reconnect();
        //Control.Preview.SetPreviewDisplay(Control.holder);
        Control.Preview.StartPreview();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `MyCamera` ? Please share more complete code, and you could refer to [Working With Audio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/working_with_audio/) and [Working With Audio sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Example_WorkingWithAudio/).

Comment: I added more complete code sample.  The issue is the live camera view doesn't restore after video capture.